# Recyclerview drag operation after item long click

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview

I am trying to perform a drag operation after user long presses on a Recyclerview item and swipes down or up. On long press, I am already starting Action mode so after user swipes down/up after long press, then only the drag has to start. I tried implementing onTouch listener on the Recyclerview but it doesn't receive ACTION_DOWN event . It receives only ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP when the finger is released. Inside the gesture listener, I start the drag. But how to capture ACTION_DOWN or swipe down/up in this scenario?

I don't want to move items like ItemTouchHelper or Drag Sort list view.

```
 recyclerAdapter.setOnItemLongClickListener(new Recycler.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
                getActivity().startActionMode(this);
                mStartDrag = true;
   }});

recyclerViewList.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            Logger.log("TAG", "On item touch"+ motionEvent.getActionMasked()); // Returns 2 (ACTION_MOVE)

            if (mStartDrag) {

                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: see if this helps - https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.1gbc3qumq

Answer (score -1):

```
viewHolder.drag.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            mStartDragListener.onStartDrag(viewHolder);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Review: Could use some explanation as well as pure-code solution.